# How to render directly screen in Java? JPanel render inside JScrollPane

Tags: java, rendering, jscrollpane

all right folks? How to render directly on screen in Java? I remeber to do this use setPixel or setRGB, but there was a way to set pixel of the main JFrame and set ZOrder even before MS-Windows components.

Here is codes and a *.ZIP file:

Mapa.java:

```
package com.primedi.ig;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import com.primedi.matlog.C32;
import com.primedi.tech.Arquivo;

public class Mapa extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String nomeMapa = null;
    private JPanel panMapa;
    private JScrollPane brPanMapa;

    public static Arquivo arqMapa = null;

    Render r = null;
    public Mapa(String nomeMapa){
        this.nomeMapa = nomeMapa;

        inicializarJanela();

        try {
            r = new Render();
            r.setBounds(658, 10, 640, 480);
        } catch (HeadlessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        getContentPane().add(r);
        setVisible(true);
        processosCons();
    }
    private void criarJanela(){
        //setTitle("zMeck - Início");
        setSize(1352, 594);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setUndecorated(true);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    private void criarPaineis(){
        panMapa = new JPanel();
        panMapa.setLayout(null);
        panMapa.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    private void criarBarrasDeRolagem(){
        brPanMapa = new JScrollPane(panMapa);
        brPanMapa.setBounds(0, 0, 658, 498);
        brPanMapa.getHorizontalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(32);
        brPanMapa.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(32);

        arqMapa = new Arquivo("mapas", "teste.pmp");
        arqMapa.carregarArquivo();
        Dimension d = new Dimension((arqMapa.linhas.get(0).length() * 32), arqMapa.linhas.size() * 32);
        panMapa.setPreferredSize(d);
    }
    private void adicionarComponentes(){
        getContentPane().add(brPanMapa);
    }
    private void inicializarJanela(){
        criarJanela();
        criarPaineis();
        criarBarrasDeRolagem();
        adicionarComponentes();
        //carregarInfosMapa();
    }
    /*private void carregarInfosMapa(){
        arqMapa = new Arquivo("mapas", nomeMapa + ".pmp");
        arqMapa.carregarArquivo();
        Dimension d = new Dimension((arqMapa.linhas.get(0).length() * 32), arqMapa.linhas.size() * 32);
        panMapa.setPreferredSize(d);
        panMapa.setVisible(true);
        for(int j = 0; j < alcanceY; j++){
            for(int i = 0; i < alcanceX; i++){
                tilesImaginarios[i][j] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tiles/tile0.PNG"));
                tilesImaginarios[i][j].setBounds((i * 32) + 658, j * 32, 32, 32);
                getContentPane().add(tilesImaginarios[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }*/

    public static int start = 0;
    private void processosCons(){
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            int posInicialScrollX = 0;
            int posInicialScrollY = 0;

            public void run() {
                if(start == 0){
                    start = 1;
                }

                if(brPanMapa.getViewport().getViewPosition().x != posInicialScrollX){
                    posInicialScrollX = brPanMapa.getViewport().getViewPosition().x;

                    Render.OFFSET_X = C32.pixelPara32(posInicialScrollX);
                    r.repaint();
                    return;
                }

                if(brPanMapa.getViewport().getViewPosition().y != posInicialScrollY){
                    posInicialScrollY = brPanMapa.getViewport().getViewPosition().y;
                    System.out.println("hello");
                    Render.OFFSET_Y = C32.pixelPara32(posInicialScrollY);
                    r.repaint();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }, 33, 33);
    }
}
```

Render.java:

```
package com.primedi.ig;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import com.primedi.tech.Arquivo;

public class Render extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static int OFFSET_X = 0;
    public static int OFFSET_Y = 0;

    public Render() throws HeadlessException {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if(Mapa.start == 1){
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

            Arquivo arq = new Arquivo("mapas", "teste.pmp");
            arq.carregarArquivo();
            for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++){
                for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
                    System.out.println(OFFSET_X);
                    Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("tiles/tile" + "" + arq.linhas.get(j + OFFSET_Y).charAt(i + OFFSET_X) + ".PNG");
                    g2d.drawImage(img1, i * 32, j * 32, this);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

C32.java:

```
package com.primedi.matlog;

public class C32 {
    public static int pixelPara32(int pixelV){
        int aprox = 0;
        int finalx = 0;
        for(aprox = 0; aprox < pixelV; aprox++);
        for(int i = 0; i < aprox; i = i + 32){
            finalx++;
        }
        return finalx;
    }
}
```

Arquivo.java:

```
package com.primedi.tech;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Arquivo {

    public ArrayList<String> linhas = new ArrayList<String>();

    public String pasta;
    public String arquivo;

    public Arquivo(String pasta, String arq){
        this.pasta = pasta;
        arquivo = arq;
    }

    public void carregarArquivo(){
        File file = new File(pasta + "/" + arquivo);

        BufferedReader br;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String linha;
            while ((linha = br.readLine()) != null) {
                linhas.add(linha);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I insert the jpanel square render inside JScrollBar, it's bug in the render process, before image total loads appears a black backgroud of JScrollPane, ridiculous.

Can help-me? Thanks very much, folks.

Here a *.ZIP If you find it better to download: https://expirebox.com/download/2b20ec8e44084c19d8bf1676d135d024.html

There is no way to reserve this screen space to render?

The bug: [bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlV5z.png)

Comment: This looks to have nothing to do with rendering specifically and all to do with threading. Your code looks to totally ignore Swing threading rules, and so while long processes are occurring, no rendering is happening. Your proposed "fix" -- direct rendering is an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) -- an incorrect solution to the problem.

Comment: Proposed Solution: look up and use a SwingWorker.

Comment: ok, sorry guy, i'll optimize this thread

Comment: Increase "brPanMapa.getComponent(0).setVisible(false);" at "criarBarrasDeRolagem"

my code continue fast, render 32x32 tile based map very fast speed!

I don't know how I guess this code, after 5h!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Increase "brPanMapa.getComponent(0).setVisible(false);" at "criarBarrasDeRolagem()"

my code continue fast, render 32x32 tile based map very fast speed!

I don't know how I guess this line of code, after 5h!

Comment: This is the real solution, my code continue fast with it.

Comment: Who unlike/denied the solution? What idiocy.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [BufferStrategy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) class.

Also, it is a bad idea to do anything other than drawing in paintComponent.
Loading images is slow due to disk i/o. If possible pre-load them and cache them in memory.

Comment: 1) This is an AWT fix. 2) This won't fix his threading issues at all.